# How to trigger Vue.js method from external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to trigger a Vue.js method from a function that is in another JavaScript file. I have given the below code which I have tried.

*sample.js*

```js
import vm from './vue.js';

function call( ) {
  vm.$options.methods.displayData('I was called externally!')
}

call()   // Here I am calling function
```

*vue.js*

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname : '' ,
    lastname : ''
  },
  methods:{
    displayData: function(s ) {
      alert(s)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to access the `$options` object:

```js
vm.displayData('I was called externally!')
```

This is simply using the instance to access its methods.

---

**Edit for your comments below:**  To use the files without a bundler or es6 modules as you want, remove the `import` statement which is only for modules.

Here are the 3 complete files you would need for *index.html*, *vue.js*, *sample.js*:

*index.html*

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>
  <script src="sample.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*vue.js*

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    firstname : '',
    lastname : ''
  }),
  methods:{
    displayData: function(s) {
      alert(s)
    }
  }
})
```

*sample.js*

```js
function call( ) {
  vm.displayData('I was called externally!')
}

call();
```